# How to import this JSON file into Firestore database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've setup an authentication process using Google Firebase. I'm now looking to start working with the Firestore database - because I need multiple collections to work with - and have a large amount of data in a JSON file that needs importing.

The JSON file looks like this. I'll post just the first two entries but there are 60 total and not something that's feasible to just type in myself.

If someone could walk me through the steps on how to utilize a script for this issue, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried to utilize some of the other posts on Stack but it's the use of scripts that has me all tripped up.

```
[
 {
   "FirstName": "Nickeil",
   "LastName": "Alexander-Williams",
   "Position": 2,
   "Age": 19,
   "CollegeYear": 2,
   "Height": 77,
   "DisplayHeight": "6-5",
   "Weight": 205,
   "College": "Virginia Tech",
   "Consistency": 46,
   "Greed": 72,
   "Loyalty": 58,
   "PlayForWinner": 16,
   "PlayingTime": 26,
   "Personality": 53,
   "Durability": 47,
   "WorkEthic": 75,
   "DunkRate": 56,
   "RARate": 3,
   "DriveKick": 58,
   "DriveShot": 0,
   "PostUp": 0,
   "PullUp": 17,
   "CS": 32,
   "Pass": 68,
   "LocATB": 30,
   "LocCorner": 81,
   "LocMidrange": 27,
   "LocPaint": 42,
   "FG_RA": 58,
   "FG_ITP": 58,
   "FG_MID": 31,
   "FG_COR": 18,
   "FG_ATB": 67,
   "FT": 0,
   "Scoring": 35,
   "Passing": 40,
   "Handling": 41,
   "OReb": 51,
   "DReb": 61,
   "Block": 52,
   "Steal": 23,
   "DrawFoul": 5,
   "Defender": 54,
   "Discipline": 75,
   "BballIQ": 65,
   "FG_RA_POT": 65,
   "FG_ITP_POT": 65,
   "FG_MID_POT": 38,
   "FG_COR_POT": 25,
   "FG_ATB_POT": 74,
   "FT_POT": 7,
   "Scoring_POT": 42,
   "Passing_POT": 47,
   "Handling_POT": 48,
   "OReb_POT": 58,
   "DReb_POT": 68,
   "Block_POT": 59,
   "Steal_POT": 30,
   "DrawFoul_POT": 12,
   "Defender_POT": 61,
   "Discipline_POT": 82,
   "BballIQ_POT": 72
 },
 {
   "FirstName": "RJ",
   "LastName": "Barrett",
   "Position": 2,
   "Age": 19,
   "CollegeYear": 1,
   "Height": 78,
   "DisplayHeight": "6-6",
   "Weight": 210,
   "College": "Duke",
   "Consistency": 61,
   "Greed": 83,
   "Loyalty": 77,
   "PlayForWinner": 80,
   "PlayingTime": 81,
   "Personality": 76,
   "Durability": 44,
   "WorkEthic": 79,
   "DunkRate": 80,
   "RARate": 17,
   "DriveKick": 51,
   "DriveShot": 28,
   "PostUp": 20,
   "PullUp": 40,
   "CS": 45,
   "Pass": 35,
   "LocATB": 40,
   "LocCorner": 84,
   "LocMidrange": 35,
   "LocPaint": 54,
   "FG_RA": 54,
   "FG_ITP": 54,
   "FG_MID": 39,
   "FG_COR": 26,
   "FG_ATB": 66,
   "FT": 2,
   "Scoring": 40,
   "Passing": 27,
   "Handling": 36,
   "OReb": 57,
   "DReb": 65,
   "Block": 37,
   "Steal": 39,
   "DrawFoul": 13,
   "Defender": 61,
   "Discipline": 54,
   "BballIQ": 58,
   "FG_RA_POT": 61,
   "FG_ITP_POT": 61,
   "FG_MID_POT": 46,
   "FG_COR_POT": 33,
   "FG_ATB_POT": 73,
   "FT_POT": 9,
   "Scoring_POT": 47,
   "Passing_POT": 34,
   "Handling_POT": 43,
   "OReb_POT": 64,
   "DReb_POT": 72,
   "Block_POT": 44,
   "Steal_POT": 46,
   "DrawFoul_POT": 20,
   "Defender_POT": 68,
   "Discipline_POT": 61,
   "BballIQ_POT": 65
 },
 .
 .
 .
]
```

Comment: With firebase, you can just pass in your json object to the update method and it just writes it. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Mocas Can you explain that? I have a JSON file in my current program and I'm using Firebase's Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while code. For import JSON to your firebase DB have no specific method but you can insert it by script. For that purpose I make this script. This might help you too.

```
const fcm = require('nodefire-realtime');

//For Initialize Firebase DB
let serviceAccountKey = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
let dbUrl = "https://<Your-project-id>.firebaseio.com/";
fcm.init(dbUrl, serviceAccountKey);

const data = require('./<your-JSON-file-name>.json');

//For insert
let dbReference = 'data/user/';
let data =data;
fcm.insert(data, dbReference);
```

Just make a simple JS file **e.g. app.js** and paste above code to it. You can get **serviceAccountKey.json** from project settings(firebase).
And if you get stuck with this package, follow steps from [nodefire-realtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodefire-realtime).  I wish this will help.